# Is there any way to externally configure mail in Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

As we use .yaml file for database configuration

```
db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']
```

Is there any way to configure mail ?

```
#mail_config
app.config['DEBUG']=True
app.config['TESTING'] = False
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT']=465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL']=True
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']=False
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = '*********@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']= '****************'                         #app password for gmail
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = '***********@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENTS'] = False
#mail_config
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask-mail provides you with a straight-out-of-the-box solution. 
You'll need the specifics of a mail provider though.

Here's the documentation
https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/